# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I want to use

```
const http = require('http');
```

says

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http'

Node version: 14.18.2

React version: 17.0.2

Comment: There is no `http` module in the browser.

Comment: You can use the [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The http module is a nodejs module. On the React App, you can only use modules that leverage the browser's capabilities. For example a popular library for calling API's and such is axios, or you could just use fetch.